# HBase Java API for HBaseTable creation shows Error

Tags: java, maven, hadoop

I am a beginner in Hadoop and Hbase. I am getting error when I try to create an HBase Table using Java API. My project is a maven Project. I am using cloudera machine for running my application. Code sample and error and POM.xml is given below

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

  // Instantiating configuration class
  Configuration con = HBaseConfiguration.create();

  HBaseAdmin admin = new HBaseAdmin(con);

  // Instantiating table descriptor class
  HTableDescriptor tableDescriptor = new HTableDescriptor(TableName.valueOf("empdata"));

  // Adding column families to table descriptor
  tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("personal"));
  tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("official"));

  // Execute the table through admin
  admin.createTable(tableDescriptor);
  System.out.println(" Table created ");
```

}

Command I am giving like this :
**-bash-4.1$ hadoop jar HBaseTableCreation-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.HBaseTable**

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration
        at com.Feathersoft.HBaseTable.main(HBaseTable.java:17)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 6 more
-bash-4.1$

POM.xml dependancies

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-common</artifactId>
    <version>0.98.8-hadoop2</version>
 </dependency>

   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.95.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-shell</artifactId>
    <version>0.98.8-hadoop2</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-protocol</artifactId>
    <version>0.98.8-hadoop2</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-thrift</artifactId>
    <version>0.98.8-hadoop2</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
    <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.5</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0a</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>11.0.2</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
     <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
     <version>2.0.0-cdh4.2.0</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.98.8-hadoop2</version>
 </dependency>
```

How can I set classpath in Cloudera Machine. I am not so much familiar in Linux.
Can any one help, It would be great ....